# Why is gradient clipping not supported with a distribution strategy in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

It looks like gradient clipping is not supported using a distribution strategy

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f9f6b4cec2a1bdc5781e4896d80cee1336a2fbab/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L383

> ("Gradient clipping in the optimizer "
> "(by setting clipnorm or clipvalue) is currently "
> "unsupported when using a distribution strategy.")

Any reason for this? I am tempted to define a custom `def _minimize(strategy, tape, optimizer, loss, trainable_variables):` with direct clipping the gradients.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub user tomerk [wrote](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33929#issuecomment-634181668):

> There's two possible places to clip when you have distribution
> strategies enabled:
>
> - before gradients get aggregated (usually wrong)
> - after gradients get aggregated (usually right & what people expect)
>
> We want it working w/ the second case (clipping after gradients are
> aggregated). The issue is the optimizers are written with clipping
> happening in the code before aggregation does.
>
> We looked into changing this, but it would have required either:
>
> - api changes that break existing users of optimizer apply_gradients/other non-minimize methods
> - changing the signatures of methods optimizer implementers need to implement, breaking existing custom optimizers
>
> So rather than:
>
> - quietly doing clipping in the wrong place
> - increasing churn & breaking existing users or existing custom optimizers just for this individual feature
>
> We instead decided to leave this disabled for now. We'll roll support
> for this into a larger optimizer refactoring that solves a larger set
> of issues.

This has now been [implemented](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/234#issuecomment-676491326).